# Registry of factories with varied arguments C++

Tags: c++, c++11, factory

I need to construct two objects, `A` and `B`. These `A` and `B` objects can be initialized in different ways.

**Design pattern to construct `A` (working):**

`A` has subclasses `A_txt`, `A_tsv`, `A_csv`, etc. Each `A` subtype is constructed from a `string` (a file path), but each one loads the file in a different way. I've built a registry that maps the file type (*e.g.* `txt`) to the appropriate factory for creating that object:

`txt` --> `A_txt_Factory`
`tsv` --> `A_tsv_Factory`
...

Where `A_txt_factory` receives a file path, loads it as a text file, and then returns a pointer to an `A_txt` object.

Together, I use this registry as a factory: given a file path and a file type, it looks up the factory corresponding to that tag and uses it to construct and returns a pointer to an `A` object.

I really like this combination registry and factory design pattern; someone else can easily make their own file type and a factory for loading it, check it into the registry, and use it without looking at the other code.

**Design pattern to construct `B` (I need help):**

Constructing `B` objects is more difficult, because they don't all load from the same type (*e.g.* all `A` subtypes are constructed with a `string` indicating the file path). `B_text` will load from a text file (from a provided `string` indicating the file path), but unlike before `B_intAndA` may initialize from an int and an instance of `A`.

What design pattern can I use to create `B`? As before, I will have a `string` tag to indicate which factory will be used; however, unlike before, each factory will accept different parameters (and possibly a different number of parameters). I suppose that could be accomplished somehow with a variadic template function of variadic parameters (I'm using C++11, so that is an option).

**Does this design pattern ever come up for anyone else (same base class, but constructed with different numbers of arguments with different types)?**

It's easy to make individual factories that construct the different `B` subtypes, but difficult to know how to allow them to be indexed with a registry since they accept different types and numbers of parameters.

How would you handle this?

Comment: Interesting problem! I guess you could play around with variadic templates and store a general `std::function` into the registry, which then gets called with the right amount of arguments.

Comment: It's just too bad that `std::function` doesn't store all its arguments as nested `std::tuple` typdef, otherwise you could extract them.

Comment: Why do you think you need a special design pattern here? If you have an `int` and and `A`, don't you already know you need to create a `B_intAndA` object? For `A` subtypes, a piece of code selects a factory at runtime. For `B` subtypes, the factory is known statically, no selection code needs to run. No code, no design pattern.

Comment: @n.m. The arguments may be different, but not necessarily; the problem of initializing `B` is like a generalized version of initializing `A`.

Comment: This is an XY problem, tell us WHY you need a generic solution to create B with a wide set of different parameters and we may be able to help. By the way, why a singleton factory? What's wrong with a simple function?

Comment: @KillianDS The factory doesn't need to be singleton (OP edited). Your question is essentially: why map to an object (and call a static or member function) rather than map to a function pointer. Both would work, but I usually prefer avoiding function pointers because it is less straightforward to optimize their calls (*e.g.* inlining) at compile time. The reason I want to allow flexibility creating `B` is that I have at least two subclasses of `B`; one inits with a file path (string), one inits with two strings (a prefix and suffix). Each performs its `B` base methods in different ways.

Comment: yes, so why do you need generic functionality to construct them? what's wrong with just calling `B1(string)` and `B2(int)` separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some time point T<sub>1</sub> the kind of B to be created, is known. The kind of B implies the signature of the constructor. At some time point T<sub>2</sub>, which might be the same or later, the B is created.

If the argument values are known at point T<sub>1</sub>, then if T<sub>2</sub> = T<sub>1</sub> just create the B here and problem solved. Otherwise if T<sub>2</sub> > T<sub>1</sub>, store the arguments and the creation call in a functor (e.g. `[=]() -> B* { return new B_int_and_A( 42, *anAPointer ); }`) and pass that, e.g. as a `std::function`, to T<sub>2</sub>.

Otherwise, if argument values are not known at point T<sub>1</sub> then you must have T<sub>2</sub> > T<sub>1</sub>, and the argument values – regardless of kind of B – must be known at T<sub>2</sub>. In this case pass a B kind id forward to T<sub>2</sub>. Then at point T<sub>2</sub> look up the arguments and creation function from the id, for example in a `switch`.

I don’t see how this has anything to do with C++, though.

What’s the connection?

Comment: C++ would handle this type of problem differently than another language, for instance Python (where constructors cannot be overloaded, but where the derived virtual table is available during calls to the base constructor).